# Slow select query with left join is null and limit results

Tags: mysql, select, performance

I have the following query that is being logged as a slow query:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT *
FROM (
`photo_data`
)
LEFT JOIN `deleted_photos` ON `deleted_photos`.`photo_id` = `photo_data`.`photo_id`
WHERE `deleted_photos`.`photo_id` IS NULL
ORDER BY `upload_date` DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Here's the output of explain:

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE  photo_data  index  NULL  upload_date  8  NULL  142523   
1  SIMPLE  deleted_photos  eq_ref  photo_id  photo_id  767  tbc.photo_data.photo_id  1  Using where; Not exists
```

I can see that it's having to go through all 142K records to pull the latest 50 out of the database.

I have these two indexes:

```
UNIQUE KEY `photo_id` (`photo_id`),
KEY `upload_date` (`upload_date`)
```

I was hoping hat the index key on upload_date would help limit the number rows. Anythoughts on what I can do to speed this up?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a field to your `photo_data` table which shows whether or not it is deleted instead of having to find out this fact by joining to another table. Then if you add an index on `(deleted, upload_date)` your query should be very fast.

Comment: So I profiled the queries the new one: 

SELECT `photo_data`.`photo_id`, `photo_data`.`image_fullsize`, `image_thumbnail`, `photo_description`
FROM (`photo_data`)
WHERE `deleted` = '0'
ORDER BY `upload_date` desc
LIMIT 50

This new spends 1.2 seconds sorting .... I added a new index on deleted ...

Comment: Steudel: Have you tried adding a combined index on `(deleted, upload_date)` as I suggested in my post? I can't remember the exact syntax for creating indexes, but something along these lines: `ALTER TABLE photo_data ADD INDEX deleted_upload_date (deleted, upload_date)`. I think that this will make a huge difference to the speed of the query as it should go from O(n log n) to almost O(1).